# Amount Sign Is Not Exporting in XML Response (Only Absolute Digits Are Exporting)

Tags: xml, tally

```xml
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
        <ID>CA_VOUCHER</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:xml</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
                <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>COMPANY NAME</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
                <SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">01-01-2023</SVFROMDATE>
                <SVTODATE TYPE="Date">31-12-2023</SVTODATE>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <FORM>CA_VOUCHER</FORM>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <PART>CA_VOUCHER</PART>
                        <XMLTAG>Vouchers.LIST</XMLTAG>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <LINE>CA_VOUCHER</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_VOUCHER:CA_VOUCHERCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHER">
                        <FIELDS>CA_DATE,CA_VOUCHERTYPENAME,CA_VOUCHERNUMBER,CA_AMOUNT</FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHER</XMLTAG>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_DATE">
                        <SET>$Date</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>DATE</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERTYPENAME">
                        <SET>$VOUCHERTYPENAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERTYPENAME</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERNUMBER">
                        <SET>$VoucherNumber</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>VOUCHERNUMBER</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_AMOUNT">
                        <SET>$AMOUNT</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>AMOUNT</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_VOUCHERCOLLECTION">
                        <TYPE> Vouchers : Ledger</TYPE>
                        <Childof>LEDGER NAME</Childof>
                        <BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>DATE</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>VOUCHERTYPENAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>VOUCHERNUMBER</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>AMOUNT</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

In the response of the above XML request, I am getting the value of Amount without a sign. (there is no negative digit for sales vouchers etc.) every amount is a positive (absolute) decimal number.
I want to export the signed value for the amount.
Please help me with what I am missing here in the mentioned request.

Comment: If currency is default, there will be no currency for amount, ask 2 questions separately,
it will be easy to find if another person has same issue.

Comment: I didn't get it, actually I want to get the signed value of amount to determine the debit or credit effect of the voucher on the ledger, because in case of sales or purchase etc this maybe simple but in case of journal voucher it is difficult to track the effect of voucher without signed value in the amount.

Comment: I want to know that wither the voucher effecting on debit or credit side of the selected ledger? If signed value of amount is not a solution is there anything with which I can determine the transaction effect.

Comment: Provided answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Type Amount for CA_AMOUNT Field

if you didn't mention type correctly it is assumed as string

Tally has [some predefined types as](https://help.tallysolutions.com/developer-reference/tally-definition-language/what-are-data-types-operators-and-expressions-in-tdl/) shown below[image]

After Change your field should like this

```
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_AMOUNT">
                        <TYPE>Amount</TYPE>
                        <SET>$AMOUNT</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>AMOUNT</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
```